# PHP on Webserver to send an image to another server and get back result

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to implement all of this in
I have a PHP file `index.php` running on a webserver (WS) on which clients upload files.

I have another server which is powerful enough (GPUs) to process these files.
My use case is, clients upload images which are sent via a `POST` request to `index.php`. Now, it has to send the file to another server (GPU) and on GPU, another PHP file, say `process.php` has to take this image, process it.

So far, I think I can implement the above with PHP's `cURL` library.

My question is mostly about how do I get the processed image back to the client?

How do I make `process.php` send back the processed  image to `index.php` and get it back to the client?

This must be a routine task but I would appreciate any help in implementing this.

code for `index.php`, I am storing the file on the webserver because I need to show a comparison (Before / After) once the processing is done. I have not yet implemented `process.php`

```
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
$storeFolder = 'uploads';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}

function cURLcheckBasicFunctions() {
  if( !function_exists("curl_init") &&
      !function_exists("curl_setopt") &&
      !function_exists("curl_exec") &&
      !function_exists("curl_close") ) return false;
  else return true;
} 

if( !cURLcheckBasicFunctions() ) 
{ echo "UNAVAILABLE: cURL Basic Functions"; }

// $url = "129.132.102.52/process.php";
$url = "dump_test.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$fp = fopen($targetFile, "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Why not just make the GPU server respond with the processed image? This way you would get the image in `$reply = curl_exec($ch);`.

Comment: Should that be done as a `POST` request again? I am not sure of how I could get the `process.php` to send the image.

Comment: Client uploads image to WS, which makes a curl request to GPU with the image, and waits for GPU to respond. GPU gets the request with the image, requires `process.php` to process the image, and when it's done with the process, it echoes the final image and exits. The processed image is therefore sent as the request response, so you will get it as the result of the curl request in WS, where you can store the image, send it back to the client, or etc. Does this makes sense? heh. I could write snippets to help with the picture if you want.

Comment: I got all that except the `it echoes the final image` part. Would that be like `echo <img src=...`? In any case, if you could write the snippets as an answer, I'd happily accept it!

Comment: Do you use Imagick or GD2 to process the image?

Comment: by process, I meant using something like an ML algorithm to do it, so i'd be running something like `exec("python some_fun.py ".$filename)` and use the image it dumped on the File system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the wait.
This is the script in WS that will receive the file from the client and will send it to GPU server. Notice I changed how the file is sent through curl (it was incorrect):

```
<?php

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = 'uploads';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}

if(!cURLcheckBasicFunctions() )
{ echo "UNAVAILABLE: cURL Basic Functions"; }

// $url = "129.132.102.52/process.php";
$url = "dump_test.php";

$file = new CURLFile($tempFile);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'file' => $file,
]);

/**
 * As you can see in the script below, the GPU will echo the processed
 * file and we will capture it here.
 */
$processedImage = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

/**
 * And now you can do anything with the processed file.
 * For example, let's save it into a file.
 */
file_put_contents('processed_image.jpg', $processedImage);

function cURLcheckBasicFunctions() {
  if( !function_exists("curl_init") &&
      !function_exists("curl_setopt") &&
      !function_exists("curl_exec") &&
      !function_exists("curl_close") ) return false;
  else return true;
}
```

And here's the script in the GPU server (this would be `process.php`):

```
<?php

$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

// Here you would process the file....

// Let's pretend you have the full path to the processed image in the $processedFilePath var.
// Now we will output the processed file contents so the WS server will receive it.

// The header isn't necessary but let's put it.
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');

echo file_get_contents($processedFilePath);
```

This script will work on PHP 5.5+. If you're using an older version, we would have to change the way the file is sent in the WS script.

Hope this is what you're looking for.