# How to make a first selected image as a thumbnail image from a list of images in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here when the user selects the images it gets append inside the `ul` tag. This all are working fine(There still might be some problems in the code below since I am very beginner in jquery).

Now what I want to change here is, the image which gets selected at first will have a `<li class='thumbnail'>` by default then other remaining selected images will not have this `thumbnail` class in the li tag. But the user later on can change the thumbnail image by clicking the image. How can I do it here ?

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
            img = `
            <li class="thumbnail">
             <div class="image">
            <img src="${e.target.result}" width="83" height="100"/>
            <div class="close"><div class="ic-close" id="img-remove"></div>
            </div>
            <p>Thumbnail</p></li>
           `
            $('#blah').append(img);

            if ( $('ul#blah li').length > 5 ) {
            $("#blah li:last-child").remove();
            alert("You can't upload more than 5 images.");           
            }
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

             $('ul#blah').on('click','.ic-close',function(e) {
                 console.log('k');
                  $(this).closest('li').remove();
                  });

        }
    }
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    

</script>
```

html

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<label for="">Upload Image</label>
 <ul class="list list-inline" id="blah">
<div class="files--upload"><input name='image' class="d-none imgUpload" type="file"                                                                     
 id="imgInp" placeholder=""/><label class="upload-label" for="imgInp">
<div class="ic-add"></div>
  <div class="mt-2">Add Photo</div>
</label></div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to add html?

Comment: in fact, it does not matter if this or that code is short or long, it is desirable to add this code to the question. Just like when the code is bundled, it simplifies the work of the programmer. It's even better if you make reproducible code.

Comment: your code adds the `img` tag to the `img` tag.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I just updated my html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to download previews is with a fast counter, which will prohibit subsequent downloads to the preview.

I have declared globally a variable:

```
var prew = true;
```

Here there is a one-time addition of a image for the preview, and also, the `prew` is assigned a `false`, which means the impossibility of further adding a image to this `div (#img_prew)`.

```
if(prew) {
   $('#img_prew').append(img);
   $('#img_prew').find('.thumbnail .image p').text('This is a preview');
   prew = false;
}
```

Created div for preview:

```
<div id="img_prew">...</div>
```

And at the end I set the width and height through css:

```
#img_prew img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```js
var prew = true;

function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();            

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                        
            img = `
            <li class="thumbnail">
             <div class="image">
            <img src="${e.target.result}" width="83" height="100"/>
            <div class="close"><div class="ic-close" id="img-remove"></div>
            </div>
            <p>Thumbnail</p></li>
           `
            if(prew) {
              $('#img_prew').append(img);
              $('#img_prew').find('.thumbnail .image p').text('This is a preview');
                prew = false;
            } 
            
            $('#blah').append(img);

            if ( $('ul#blah li').length > 5 ) {
            $("#blah li:last-child").remove();
            alert("You can't upload more than 5 images.");           
            }
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

             $('ul#blah').on('click','.ic-close',function(e) {
                 console.log('k');
                  $(this).closest('li').remove();
                  });

        }
    }
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

```css
#img_prew img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<label for="">Upload Image</label>
<div id="img_prew"></div>
 <ul class="list list-inline" id="blah">
<div class="files--upload"><input name='image' class="d-none imgUpload" type="file"                                                                     
 id="imgInp" placeholder=""/><label class="upload-label" for="imgInp">
<div class="ic-add"></div>
  <div class="mt-2">Add Photo</div>
</label></div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Now  here what i encounter another problem is that I am being unable to pass these selected images files to the backend . Only the first one image which was selected at first get sends to the backend. Do you have any idea why might this happen ?

Comment: Show me how you transfer images to the backend.

Comment: I am using this input name attribute for the files  `<input name='image' type="file"`

Comment: no, i mean, something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250223/php-on-webserver-to-send-an-image-to-another-server-and-get-back-result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225933/discussion-between-d-p-and-sergey-kuznetsov).